# BitmapFactory.Options throw nullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have the following code where I try to rescale a bitmap:

```
  FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File(getCachePath(context), makeCacheFileName(uri)));

            //Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            value = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null, o);

            value = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                    value, // bitmap to resize
                    o.outWidth, // new width
                    o.outHeight, // new height
                    true); // bilinear filtering

            stream.close();
```

The log is the following:

```
  01-04 16:24:18.101: E/AndroidRuntime(27524): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  01-04 16:24:18.101: E/AndroidRuntime(27524): java.lang.NullPointerException
  01-04 16:24:18.101: E/AndroidRuntime(27524):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:344)
  01-04 16:24:18.101: E/AndroidRuntime(27524):  at com.network.ImageThreadLoader$DiskCache.get(ImageThreadLoader.java:295)
  01-04 16:24:18.101: E/AndroidRuntime(27524):  at com.network.ImageThreadLoader.loadImageFromCache(ImageThreadLoader.java:185)
  01-04 16:24:18.101: E/AndroidRuntime(27524):  at com.products.ProductListAdapter.switchImages(ProductListAdapter.java:119)
  01-04 16:24:18.101: E/AndroidRuntime(27524):  at com.products.ProductListAdapter.access$0(ProductListAdapter.java:79)
  01-04 16:24:18.101: E/AndroidRuntime(27524):  at com.products.ProductListAdapter$1.run(ProductListAdapter.java:73)
  01-04 16:24:18.101: E/AndroidRuntime(27524):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
  01-04 16:24:18.101: E/AndroidRuntime(27524):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
  01-04 16:24:18.101: E/AndroidRuntime(27524):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
  01-04 16:24:18.101: E/AndroidRuntime(27524):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
  01-04 16:24:18.101: E/AndroidRuntime(27524):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  01-04 16:24:18.101: E/AndroidRuntime(27524):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
  01-04 16:24:18.101: E/AndroidRuntime(27524):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
  01-04 16:24:18.101: E/AndroidRuntime(27524):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
  01-04 16:24:18.101: E/AndroidRuntime(27524):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nick, BitmapFactory.decodeStream must be returning null which means it's failing to decode the stream.  Possibly the value in the file is bad or you were unable to open the file.  Check 'stream'  for null.